# Re-installing Ubuntu on Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a dual boot system installed with this [guide](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony), where 50Gb are for Win7, 50Gb are for LinuxMint, and the remainder is for miscellaneous data.

I had some issues with my Mint and I want to reinstall Ubuntu on that partition. I customized the GRUB loader (with `grub-customizer`), but aside from that, the other partitions of my system should be unaltered from the Linux PoV.

Can I safely re-install Ubuntu on the Linux partition (erasing Mint) without harming the rest of my data? What precautions should I take (aside from saving important files into an external hard drive)? Are there any expected issues with partitions (resizing, erasing, or in some way altering other partitions except the one I'm installing on)?

For some additional information, running `fdisk -l` shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x73f06436

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   104857599    52325376    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       104857600   209715199    52428800   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       209715200   500117503   145201152    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:**

*Why not use VirtualBox if you want to hold onto Windows? or better yet Why don't you run ESXI inside a Docker container?*

Docker would make creation and deletion much faster and there would be less error that might occur. 
I would say that this could be a better, safer way to achieve this goal.

You could always go the other route and use Virtualbox and install `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` from Oracles website so you could have a more user friendly environment.

Personally I would scrap Windows all together. If I HAD to have windows on my machine I would run ESXI inside of a Docker container. Data backup wouldn't even be necessary(I say that lightly...ALWAYS backup) since you aren't manipulating partitions.

Comment: Windows for games, Linux for work. Both require high performance, which VBox (or VMware or else) don't really support (on my hardware and for the applications I need to run, anyway)

Comment: If thats the case just boot from a Ubuntu ISO and select /dev/sda3  to install on.  You shouldn't have any issues. Are you concerned about data loss on the windows machine? Or are you more concerned you are going to overwrite it and then have to go pay $200 to get an OS? Why not create a backup disk of Windows?  [ http://www.howtogeek.com/223139/how-to-create-an-image-of-your-pc-before-upgrading-to-windows-10/ ] or you could clone your HDD if you have a dual hardrive dock and an extra HDD laying around.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering what happened, I backed-up my files into an external hard drive, burned Ubuntu onto a USB stick, rebooted, deleted the Mint partition and installed Ubuntu on it (one more, following the [guide](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony)).

I added a [SWAP file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/), cleaned up the interface somewhat, installed [NTFS-config](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/ntfs-config/) to mount my other partitions on start-up and removed keychain's password to avoid all that spam at start-up. I installed [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to get GRUB to recognize Windows again and remove all the other options from boot, and everything is running smooth.